# Speed logic for pygame game

Tags: python, pygame

I'm doing a final project for my coding class at school. I learnt from a tutorial online on how to use pygame by making pong. Then, I decided to create an Undertale battle system with the knowledge I had gained from learning how to make pong in pygame. I have come across an issue however, and its regarding the heart's speed.

Here is the code:

```py
import pygame
import sys

# setup
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# main window
screen_width = 900
screen_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Undertale')
icon = pygame.image.load('heart.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# game rectangles
heart = pygame.image.load('heart.png')
DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE = (20, 20)
heart_img = pygame.transform.scale(heart, DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE)
battle_width = 10
battle_height = 200
middle_offset = 30
length = 200 + 2*battle_width
battle_left = pygame.Rect(screen_width/2 - 100, screen_height/2 + middle_offset, battle_width, battle_height)
battle_right = pygame.Rect(screen_width/2 + 100 + battle_width, screen_height/2 + 30, battle_width, battle_height)
battle_up = pygame.Rect(screen_width/2 - 100, screen_height/2 + middle_offset, length, battle_width)
battle_down = pygame.Rect(screen_width/2 - 100, screen_height/2 + middle_offset + battle_height, length, battle_width)

# colours
bg_color = pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

# game vars
heart_x = screen_width/2
heart_y = screen_height/2 + middle_offset + battle_height/2 - 10
# Using half of Default Image Size Width
heart_speed_x = 0
heart_speed_y = 0
speed = 4

while True:
    # input handles
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                heart_speed_x -= speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                heart_speed_x += speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                heart_speed_y -= speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                heart_speed_y += speed
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                heart_speed_x += speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                heart_speed_x -= speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                heart_speed_y += speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                heart_speed_y -= speed

    # logic
    heart_x += heart_speed_x
    heart_y += heart_speed_y
    heart_rect = heart_img.get_rect(topleft=(heart_x, heart_y))
    if heart_rect.colliderect(battle_left) or heart_rect.colliderect(battle_right):
        heart_speed_x *= -1
    if heart_rect.colliderect(battle_up) or heart_rect.colliderect(battle_down):
        heart_speed_y *= -1

    # visuals
    screen.fill(bg_color)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, battle_left)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, battle_right)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, battle_up)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, battle_down)
    screen.blit(heart_img, (heart_x, heart_y))

    # window update
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

The heart is the player. I want it to be able to move around inside the box, and I do not want it to come out, I want it to stay inside. I made it so that the heart image is a rectangle so that it can collide with the box. It worked, but the speed makes it so that the heart is constantly moving, I want it to stop whenever the `KEYUP` event occurs. And that's what I did, yet it refused to cooperate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

```
heart_x += 0 - heart_speed_x
```

and

```
heart_y += 0 - heart_speed_y
```

The problem was that the either or both of the x and y position constantly changed after hitting the surface. This was because the speed of the variables stayed the same. So in the solution, I made it so that the x any y positions only change once once it conditionally checks for collision.